# Can't get commands inside .bash_profile startup script to run

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bash

From my bash shell (latest version of Lion) if I issue the command...

```
source ~/sh/bashmarks.sh
```

The bashmarks.sh script will run and the functionality it provides is available.  However I don't want to manually run this script so I have tried to put it into my ~/.bash_profile (the above command is the only thing in the file).

If I quit Terminal and then restart it, the ~/.bash_profile runs, but it reports...

```
: command not found
```

How can I get the commands contained in this script to run when the Terminal is opened?  I know the correct .bash_profile is being run, because I can modify the file with some other commands and those don't work either, but the point being is I can see the output change when I modify the contents of the file and restart the shell.  So it is picking up the right ~ user directory (I am the only account on the machine).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does your `.bash_profile` have DOS-style line endings? Strange error messages like that often are "corrupted" by a `\r` character.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!  I think I originally edited this file from the Windows side, and was subsequently editing from the Mac side, but there must have been some leftover control characters.